# ImageGrab.grab not get widget of tkinter window, but screen area under it

Tags: python, tkinter, imagegrab

Try to capture the image of a widget in tkinter window by following code, but just get the screen area under tkinter window.

```py
import ctypes
import platform
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import ImageGrab

if platform.system() == "Windows" and platform.release() == "10":
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("+0+0")

var = tk.StringVar()
var.set("Hello World")
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40, bg='green', takefocus=False, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

root.update()
# sleep(1)

x, y = entry.winfo_rootx(), entry.winfo_rooty()
width, height = entry.winfo_width(), entry.winfo_height()

im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x+width, y+height))    # Grab image on screen
im.show()

root.mainloop()
```

It will be OK if line `# sleep(1)` replaced by `sleep(1)`. Had been tried method `update` or `update_idletasks`, all got same results.

Is there any method to finalize tkinter window immediately ? So I don't need to sleep one second each time to grap image of a widget. Or I get wrong way to go it, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Put it inside a function and then `root.after(1000,func)`. It is just due to the fact that it happens fast but the window is not fully shown in that time.

Comment: It is same, I still need to wait 1 second ... after widget finalized. I have lot of widgets to capture images initially, then need to capture and move image to follow movement of mouse. So lomg time to wait or to sleep may delay the action.

Comment: So you are asking for some method to speed up the window showing up?

Comment: Remember that tkinter, like all GUI frameworks, is event based.  Your windows are not drawn when they are created.  Instead, the creation just sends a message.  The purpose of the mainloop is to read any pending messages and dispatch them for processing.  So, NOTHING gets drawn until you get into mainloop.  So, you need to do some timer callbacks to make sure the windows are drawn.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think window is supposed to be _drawn_ with `root.update`, it is just that it takes time to pop the window up, and `PIL` grabs the coordinates quickly while the window is still almost being _drawn_.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tested it with `sleep(3);print('mainloop'); root.mainloop() `  after `root.update()`, window did finalize and shown, then 'mainloop' printed after 3 seconds.

Comment: Is there any method to finalize tkinter window **immediately** ? It looks like that methods update and update_idletasks still wait some time or idle to update GUI of window.

Comment: Did you look into the function `root.wait_visibility(w)`?  It's supposed to wait until widget w becomes visible.  I've never used it but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Code will wait and block at `root.wait_visibility()` for nothing changed.

Comment: You're hacking here, trying a bunch of random stuff and hoping something sticks.  That's poor programming.  Learn to do event-driven programming as it is designed to be used, and you won't have to re-do it later.

Comment: No, it's not true. Just try to show my question in short and executable code. Actually it will be event-drivern for mouse clicking event. It will work like a tooltip, but I want drag a widget in a new generated window and I cannot wait too long time before it.

Comment: Are you still waiting for a better answer? If not, would appreciate marking the one below as correct :D

Comment: I didn't get the correct answer for this issue, it still wait time to grab widget.

Comment: @JasonYang Because there is no way to do so...?

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious right? It needs to take some time to show the window but the screenshot is captured quite quickly. What do I suggest? Put it inside a function and take advantage of the `after` method here.

```
def screenshot():
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x+width, y+height))    # Grab image on screen
    im.show()

root.after(1000,screenshot) # Depending on the time required to take show the window
```